# Dual boot ubuntu 18.04 and windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, grub

I have installed fresh windows 10 and installed ubuntu 18.04 in my HP pavilon laptop. now when I restart the computer , It automatically starts the windows 10.

so If I want ubuntu I need to reboot the system and hit `f9` and brings up BOOTMANAGER with the following options

- `OS windows bootmanager`
- `ubuntu`

I select ubuntu it takes me to the `GRUB` which contains everything I want.

- `ubuntu`
- `*advance option ubuntu`
- `Windows .....`

I would like when the laptop is restarted automatically it should display `GRUB`  so that I can select which system I want to use currently.

what am I missing to get this work as I want?

Comment: Open UEFI settings, find the boot menu and where it says "windows bot manager" replace with "ubuntu". It's that simple.

Comment: where do I find those settings ? via bios? please can you give clear guide on this?

Comment: You don't have BIOS, you have UEFI but yes, it does the same. And, like old BIOS, UEFI is unique to brand/model. Supposedly you were already there to change to boot the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: I mean I can access uefi but how do I replace os window bootmanager with ubuntu??

Comment: As previously commented, find the boot menu. Somewhere you'll see "windows boot loader", navigate to select it, usually with enter (but follow the specific instructions), the "ubuntu"option should appear, select it instead of windows, confirm. For detailed instructions consult your user's manual.

Comment: there is not option to change as u suggested thanks anyway for help

Comment: If you have the "ubuntu" option with F9 then you can make it permanent as the default boot priority. Check the user's manual or online for detailed and specific instructions.

Comment: thanks bro, I solved the issued , just needed to repair grub

Comment: Not bro but I'm glad you solved even if I'm not sure about how exactly.

Comment: Oh OK, now with your answer I get it: You installed a program to do what you could have done manually in a couple of minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

After gooogling I found solution for HP Pavilon

Boot to your ubuntu system and enter the following command via terminal

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

  launch Boot-Repair from either :
      the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
      or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

  Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
  If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Warning: the default settings are the ones used by the "Recommended Repair". Changing them may worsen your problem. Don't modify them before creating a BootInfo URL, and asking for advice on Ubuntu Forums Absolute Beginners Section or in Installation and Upgrades.

> NOTE: After launching the repair please  just follow the default recommendation

reboot your system you should see a `GRUB` with all option u need